# Implementing Grafana monitoring tool for ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am implementing Prometheus with ActiveMQ Artemis using the [corresponding metrics plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin).

I have configured the Prometheus Metrics Plugin and added the required libraries and WAR file to the Artemis-specific folder. Do I need to add any additional configurations in the `broker.xml` for showing data?

I am planning to use this [sample Grafana dashboard](https://github.com/artemiscloud/grafana/blob/master/ActiveMQArtemisSampleDashboard.json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana takes the data for its graphs and visualizations from Prometheus so as long as Prometheus is able to scrape the data from the HTTP endpoint on ActiveMQ Artemis (i.e. the one exposed by the plugin) then everything should work. You don't need to add anything else to `broker.xml` other than the metrics plugin configuration.

Comment: which data source need to be use after upload the Grafana JSON

Comment: I recommend you create a new question with additional details to clarify the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: Okay Thank you for the above question